# why do ampersands become html codes when converting with php json_encode

Tags: javascript, php

I have an array in php that I am parsing to a javascript.  My problem is that some of the strings in the array contain ampersands, and they become `&amp;` instead of `&` in the javascript. Here is a simple example to illustrate my issue:

```
<? $titles = json_encode(array("H&M", "Tesco")); ?>

<script>
var titles = <? echo $titles; ?>; 
console.log(titles[0]);
</script>
```

the log reads:

```
H&amp;M
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem correct, can you take a look again to generate a working example? You don't have a closing parentheses at the end of your PHP line, you call json_encode twice, and you reference $search_titles, which doesn't exist in the snippet you've posted.

Comment: PHP does not entitize amphersands in `json_encode`. It leaves them alone unless you tell it to convert to hex with an option param. Code which you have not shown us must be causing your problem. Also, your code sample has syntax errors, wrong variable names and double `json_encode` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because that's how the HTTP protocol divides the elements of a GET or POST transaction. This will solve the problem on the javascript end:

```
var convertAmpersand = function(str) {
  return str.replace(/&amp;/g, "\&");
};

console.log(convertAmpersand(titles[0]));
```

Comment: There is no technology involved in the posted code which should assume data will be contained in a query string or post body, and entitizing would be the wrong way to handle it even if it were. Something else is wrong.

Comment: You're right @JAAulde, there was nothing in the code to suggest that the data would be in a query string or post body. The "entitizing" as you put it is done by the PHP json_encode function and the ampersand is the only character to which it happens... to be used for POST and GET operations.

Comment: Instead of editing my previous comment, I'll just say I was wrong. @JAAulde, you're right about the json_encode function; it doesn't convert ampersands. The ampersands are actually being converted to HTML entities when the server is sending the page to the browser.

Comment: The server does no such conversion on output. The OP simply cannot have shown all the code.

Comment: Regardless, the OP came here for a solution. That's what I gave him.

Comment: Yeah, I hear ya. It would concern me to see the symptom fixed without understanding the cause, though.

Comment: Well, instead of arguing further, I tested with this code `<?php $items = array(); $items[] = "H&M"; print json_encode($items); ?>`. You are correct. If it were my code, I'd like to know why that's happening. I proposed an instant gratification fix, not to say it's the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps others, I was doing something similar to your example, but using jQuery to read a JSON string that I had injected into an HTML element.

As mentioned in some of the comments, PHP was not doing the `& => &amp;` encoding. It was being done in javascript. The solution was to use jQuery's `.text()` instead of `.html()`:

PHP:

```
<div id="bootstrap"><?= json_encode(array("H&M", "Tesco")) ?></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
  // uses &amp;
  var asHtml = $('#bootstrap').html();
  console.log(asHtml);

  // uses &
  var asText = $('#bootstrap').text();
  console.log(asText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in opencart.

```
$json = array(
   'href' => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=1'),
);
echo json_encode($json);
```

It occured that `link` function was deliberately creating `&amp;`. From source code:

```
$url .= '&amp;' . http_build_query($args);
```

I ended

```
str_replace('&amp;','&',$this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=1'))
```